# Can I use huggingface inference endpoint to generate embeddings and use them in llamaindex nodes?

Tags: langchain, huggingface, llama-index

Can I use huggingface inference endpoint to generate embeddings and use them in llamaindex nodes?

I am able to to successfully genereate embeddings via a huggingface inference endpoint, but I am not sure on the correct implementation of adding the embeddings to the nodes by llamaindex.

I want to replicate what this notebook does but using a huggingface inference endpoint:

https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/node_postprocessor/MetadataReplacementDemo.html

motivation: handle embedding generation in production

any recommendations / suggestions on how to implement this?

I am using this to get embeddings:

```
endpoint = ""
api_org = ""

import requests

class HuggingFaceEmbedder:
    def __init__(self, endpoint, api_org):
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.api_org = api_org
        self.headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.api_org}'
        }

    def embed_documents(self, texts):
        if not isinstance(texts, list):
            raise ValueError("Input 'texts' must be a list of strings.")

        # Prepare the input data
        input_data = {"inputs": texts}

        # Make the request
        res = requests.post(self.endpoint, headers=self.headers, json=input_data)

        if res.status_code == 200:
            return res.json()['embeddings']
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Request failed with status code {res.status_code}: {res.text}")


embedder = HuggingFaceEmbedder(endpoint, api_org)'''
```

this is how the documentation does it without the inference endpoint:

```
from llama_index import ServiceContext, set_global_service_context
from llama_index.llms import OpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings import OpenAIEmbedding, HuggingFaceEmbedding
from llama_index.node_parser import SentenceWindowNodeParser, SimpleNodeParser

# create the sentence window node parser w/ default settings
node_parser = SentenceWindowNodeParser.from_defaults(
    window_size=3,
    window_metadata_key="window",
    original_text_metadata_key="original_text",
)
simple_node_parser = SimpleNodeParser.from_defaults()

llm = OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.1)
embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2", max_length=512
)
ctx = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=llm,
    embed_model=embed_model,
    # node_parser=node_parser,
)



from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(
    input_files=["./IPCC_AR6_WGII_Chapter03.pdf"]
).load_data()


nodes = node_parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)



from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex

sentence_index = VectorStoreIndex(nodes, service_context=ctx)
```

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to get this working?